# Operands mismatch for mul when inserting asm into c

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to make an assembly insert into C code. However when I try to multiply two registers inside it I get an error calling for operands mismatch. I tried `"mul %%bl, %%cl\n"` (double %% because it's in C code). From my past experience with asm I think this should work. I also tried `"mul %%cl\n"` (moving bl to al first), but in this case I get tons of errors from linker

```
zad3:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `len'
/tmp/ccJxYyIp.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
zad3: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
zad3: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
zad3: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
zad3:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
zad3: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: (.text+0x0): first defined here
zad3: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x10): multiple definition of `str'
/tmp/ccJxYyIp.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `str' changed from 4 in   /tmp/ccJxYyIp.o to 9 in zad3
zad3: In function `main':
(.text+0xf6): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/ccJxYyIp.o:zad3.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
zad3: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
zad3:(.data+0x20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in zad3(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From what I understand, it tells me I defined len and a few other variables a few times, but I cannot see this multiple definition.
The goal of my program is to take a string of numbers and count sum of them but using 2 as a base. So let's say string is 293, then I want to count `2*2^2+9*2^1+3*2^0`
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char str[] = "543";
const int len = 3;

int main(void)
{
asm(
"mov $0, %%rbx \n"
"mov $1, %%rcx \n"

"potega: \n" 
"shl $1, %%cl \n" 
"inc %%rbx \n"
"cmp len, %%ebx \n"
"jl potega \n"


"mov $0, %%rbx \n" 

"petla: \n" 
"mov (%0, %%rbx, 1), %%al \n" 

"sub $48, %%al \n"

"mul %%al, %%cl \n"  
"shr $1, %%cl \n"    

"add $48, %%al \n"

"mov %%al, (%0, %%rbx, 1) \n" 

"inc %%rbx \n"  
"cmp len, %%ebx \n" 
"jl petla \n" 

:"r"(&str)
:"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx" 
);
printf("Wynik: %s\n", str);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your [mcve] don't compile.

Comment: @Stargateur: Well, yeah, the question _is_ about a compile-time error..

Comment: @Michael yeah, sorry ^^' I mean that I don't get the same error, XD. `error: expected ‘(’ before ‘,’ token :"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx"`.

Comment: The `len` is defined just once in available sources, so you are either including something else, or your linking phase arguments are wrong. `mul cl,bl` is not valid x86 opcode, that's correct. Check the [`MUL`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html) docs for exact in/out variants, actually [`IMUL`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_138.html) may be more friendly to inline-asm black magic (I can't help with that). BTW, you don't need to multiply by powers of two with `mul/imul`, just shift left the value by the power. I.e. 9*2^1 == 9<<1 and 3*2^2 == 3<<2

Comment: The 'token' error is due to needing an additional `:` before `"r"`

Comment: Also I'm not sure... is `"r"(&str)` correct? Isn't it like in C, that `&str` is pointer of pointer, instead of the pointer to string? (but I don't know how inline asm works, so I may be just wrong). And you are writing the results back into string as single digit, so for example 9*2^1 = 18 => 18+48 = 66 = 'B' ... was that your goal?

Comment: Try removing the `const` from `len` (or add it as a parameter to the asm).

Comment: Why do you write this as inline assembly? You just make your own life difficult.

Comment: @fuz - I believe this is a student's homework.  Every few weeks we see something that feels similar.  Apparently there's a teacher out there who believes inline asm is a good way to teach assembler.  I disagree, but I can only talk to the students, not the teacher.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd must be some secret "teach assembly in most irrelevant/annoying way possible" challenge. I'm just not sure how to pick a winner, surely AT&T syntax inlined assembly is pure evil, but then you have here students asking about emu8086 and/or animation done by DOS 18.2Hz timer while drawing on screen through BIOS interrupt... Yep, I wouldn't want to judge winner of this one.

Comment: I am their teacher @DavidWohlferd : We must teach them how to use GCC inline assembly correctly before they go into the work force and do it wrong! ;-)

Comment: As for all the multiple redefinition messages we'd need to see how you compile and link (the actual commands you use) the code to become an executable.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I compiled the file with `gcc my_file.c -o my_exec` 

@Ped7g Actually you're right, I haven't thought of it. I wanted to write 18 as "18". Actually haven't realised how easily I can go more than one digit. 

@DavidWohlferd Yes, it's students assigment. Inline asm is topic for only one classes, but still I have some homework. And as you can see - I just don't feel this assembly stuff.

Comment: @wylfryd Are we making any progress?  Have the suggestions here helped at all?  I'm a bit stumped about the duplicate symbols.  Have you tried doing just a [Hello World](http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/c/hworld.html) program to make sure your compiler is working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As somebody pointed out - yes it's a student exercise. 
When it comes to my original problem, when I removed line `add $48,%%al \n"` it worked. I also switched to `mul %%cl`.

When it comes to rest of problems, you pointed out, I talked with my professor and she slightly changed her mind (or I got the assgment wrong the first time - whatever you find more possible) and now she wanted me to return an argument from the inline function and  said the intiger type was good. It resulted in me writing such piece of code (which actually does what I wanted)

example: "543" -> 5*(2^2)+4*(2^1)+3*(2^0)=31

```
#include <stdio.h>
char str[] = "543";
const int len = 3;
int len1 = 2;
int result;

int main(){
asm(
    "mov $0, %%rbx\n"
    "mov $1, %%rcx\n"
    "mov $0, %%rdx\n"

    "potega: \n"
    "inc %%rbx\n"
    "shl $1, %%cl\n"
    "cmp len1, %%ebx \n"
    "jl potega\n"

    "mov $0, %%rbx\n"

    "petla:\n"
    "mov (%0, %%rbx, 1), %%al\n"
    "sub $48, %%al\n"
    "mul %%cl\n"
    "shr $1, %%cl\n"
    "add %%al, %%dl\n"
    "inc %%rbx\n"
    "cmp len, %%ebx\n"
    "jl petla\n"

    "movl %%edx, result\n"

    ://"=r"(result)

    :"r"(&str), "r"(&result)

    :"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"

);
printf("Wynik: %d\n", result);
return 0;
}
```

Also - I do realise, that normally you return variables the way it's showed in comment, but it didn't work, so by my professor's suggestion I wrote the program this way.

Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: Generally I avoid doing people's homework for them.  But now that you have 'solved' this, would you be interested in some feedback about how you might do this differently?  Or have you already moved on?

Comment: @David I'd be very curious to find out why the commented version of returning an argument didn't work. But sure, if you have some good ideas I'm happy to hear them and learn :)

Answer (score 3):

While I try to avoid "doing people's homework" for them, you have already solved this and given that it has been over a week, have probably already turned it in.

So, looking at your final solution, there are a few things you might want to consider doing differently.  In no particular order:

1. Comments.  While all code needs comments, asm REALLY needs comments.  As you'll see from my solution (below), having comments alongside the code really helps clarify what the code does.  It might seem like a homework project hardly needs them.  But since you posted this here, 89 people have tried to read this code.  Comments would have made this easier for all of us.  Not to mention that it will make life easier for your 'future self,' when you come back months from now to try to maintain it.  Comments.  Nuff said.
2. Zeroing registers.  While `mov $0, %%rbx` will indeed put zero in rbx, this is not the most efficient way to zero a register.  Using `xor %%rbx, %%rbx` is both (microscopically) faster and produces (slightly) smaller executable code.
3. potega.  Without comments, it took me a bit to sort out what you were doing in your first loop.  You are using rbx to keep track of how many characters you have processed, and cl gets shifted one to the left for each character.  A few thoughts here:

   3a. First thing I'd do is look at moving the `shl $1, %%cl` out of the loop.  Instead of doing both increment and shift, just count the characters, then do a single shift of the appropriate size.  This is (slightly) complicated by the fact that if you want to shift by a variable amount, the amount must be specified in cl (ie `shl %%cl, %%rbx`).  Why cl?  Who knows?  That's just how `shl` works.  So you'd want to do the counting in cl instead of rbx.

   3b. Second thing about this loop has to do with `len1`.  Since you already *know* the size (it's in `len1`), why would you even need a loop?  Perhaps a more sensible approach would be:

   3c. Strings in C are terminated with a null character (aka 0).  If you want to find the length of a string, normally you'd walk the string until you find it.  This removes the requirement to even have `len1`.

   3d. Your code assumes that the input string is valid.  What would happen if you got passed "abc"?  Or ""?  Validating parameters is boring, time consuming, and makes the program bigger and run slower.  On the other hand, it pays HUGE dividends when something unexpected goes wrong.  At the very least you should specify your assumptions about your input.

   3e. Using global variables is usually a bad idea.  You run into naming collisions (2 files both using the name len1), code in several different files all changing the value (making bugs difficult to track down) and it can make your program bigger than it needs to be.  There are times when globals are useful, but this does not appear to be one of them.  The only purpose here seems to be to allow access to these variables from within the asm, and there are other ways to do that.

   3f. You use `%0` to refer to `str`.  That works (and is better than accessing the global symbol directly), but it is harder to read than it needs to be.  You can associate a name with the parameter and use that instead.

Let's take a break for a moment to see what we've got so far:

```
     "xor %%rcx, %%rcx\n"             // Zero the strlen count

  // Count how many characters in string
  "potega%=: \n\t"

     "mov (%[pstr], %%rcx), %%bl\n\t" // Read the next char

     "test %%bl, %%bl \n\t"           // Check for 0 at end of string
     "jz kont%= \n\t"

     "cmp $'0', %%bl\n\t"             // Ensure digit is 0-9
     "jl gotowe%=\n\t"
     "cmp $'9', %%bl\n\t"
     "jg gotowe%=\n\t"

     "inc %%rcx \n\t"                 // Increment index/len
     "jmp potega%= \n"

  "kont%=:\n\t"

  // rcx = the number of character in the string excluding null
```

You'll notice that I'm using `%=` at the end of all the labels.  You can read about what this does in the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate), but mostly it just appends a number to the labels.  Why do that?  Well, if you wanted to try computing multiple strings in a single run (like I do below), you might call this code several times.  But compilers (being the tricky devils that they are) might choose to "inline" your assembler.  That would mean you'd have several chunks of code that all had the same label names in the same routine.  Which would cause your compile to fail.

Note that I don't check to see if the string is "too long" or NULL.  Left as an exercise for the student...

Ok, what else?

4. petla.  Mostly my code matches yours.

   4a. I did change to `sub $'0', %%al` instead of just using $48.  It does the same thing, but subtracting '0' seems to me to be more "self-documenting."

   4b. I also slightly reordered things to put the `shr` at the end.  Why do that?  You use `cmp` along with `jz` to see when it's time to exit the loop.  The way `cmp` works is that it sets some flags in the flags register, then `jz` looks at those flags to figure out whether to jump or not.  However `shr` sets those flags too.  Each time you shift, you are moving that '1' further and further to the right.  What happens when it's at the rightmost position and you shift it 1 more?  You get zero.  At which point the "jump if not zero" (aka `jnz`) works as expected.  Since you have to do the `shr` anyway, why not use it to tell you when to exit the loop too?

That gives me:

```
  "petla%=:\n\t"

     "mov (%[pstr], %%rcx, 1), %%al\n\t" // read the next char
     "sub $'0', %%al\n\t"                // convert char to value
     "mul %%bl\n\t"                      // mul bl * al -> ax
     "add %%ax, %[res]\n\t"              // Accumulate result
     "inc %%rcx\n\t"                     // move to next char
     "shr $1, %%rbx\n\t"                 // decrease our exponent
     "jnz petla%=\n"                     // Has our exponent gone to 0?

  "gotowe%=:"
```

Lastly, the parameters:

```
  :[res] "=r"(result)
  :[pstr] "r"(str), "0"(0)

  :"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "cc"
```

I'm going to store the result in the C variable named `result`.  Since I specify `=r` with this constraint, I know that it is stored in a register, although I don't know which register the compiler will pick.  But I don't need to.  I can just refer to it using `%[res]` and let the compiler sort it out.  Likewise I refer to the string using `%[pstr]`.  I could use %0 like you did, except that since I've added `result`, `pstr` isn't %0 anymore, it's %1 (`result` is now %0).  This is another reason to use names instead of numbers.

That last bit (`"0"(0)`) might take a bit of explaining.  Using `"0"` for the constraint (instead of say `"r"`) tells the compiler to put this value into the same place as parameter #0.  The `(0)` says store a zero there before starting the asm.  In other words, initialize the register that is going to hold `result` to 0.  Yes, I could do this in the asm.  But I prefer to let the compiler do this for me.  While it may not matter in a tiny program like this, letting the C compiler do as much work as possible tends to produce the most efficient code.

So, when we wrap this all together, I get:

```
/*

my_file.c - The goal of this program is to take a string of numbers and 
count sum of them but using 2 as a base.

example: "543" -> 5*(2^2)+4*(2^1)+3*(2^0)=31

*/

#include <stdio.h>

void TestOne(const char *str)
{
   short result;

   // Code assumes str is not NULL.  Strings with non-digits and zero
   // length strings return 0.

   asm(
         "xor %%rcx, %%rcx\n"             // Zero the strlen count

      // Count how many characters in string
      "potega%=: \n\t"

         "mov (%[pstr], %%rcx), %%bl\n\t" // Read the next char

         "test %%bl, %%bl \n\t"           // Check for 0 at end of string
         "jz kont%= \n\t"

         "cmp $'0', %%bl\n\t"             // Ensure digit is 0-9
         "jl gotowe%=\n\t"
         "cmp $'9', %%bl\n\t"
         "jg gotowe%=\n\t"

         "inc %%rcx \n\t"                 // Increment index/len
         "jmp potega%= \n"

      "kont%=:\n\t"

      // rcx = the number of character in the string excluding null

         "dec %%rcx \n\t"       // We want to shift rbx 1 less than pstr length
         "jl gotowe%=\n\t"      // Check for zero length string

         "mov $1, %%rbx\n\t"    // Set exponent for first digit
         "shl %%cl, %%rbx\n\t"

         "xor %%rcx, %%rcx\n"   // Reset string index

      "petla%=:\n\t"

         "mov (%[pstr], %%rcx, 1), %%al\n\t" // read the next char
         "sub $'0', %%al\n\t"                // convert char to value
         "mul %%bl\n\t"                      // mul bl * al -> ax
         "add %%ax, %[res]\n\t"              // Accumulate result
         "inc %%rcx\n\t"                     // move to next char
         "shr $1, %%rbx\n\t"                 // decrease our exponent
         "jnz petla%=\n"                     // Has our exponent gone to 0?

      "gotowe%=:"

      :[res] "=r"(result)
      :[pstr] "r"(str), "0"(0)

      :"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "cc"
   );

   printf("Wynik: \"%s\" = %d\n", str, result);
}

int main(){

   TestOne("x");
   TestOne("");
   TestOne("5");
   TestOne("54");
   TestOne("543");
   TestOne("5432");

   return 0;
}
```

Notice: No global variables.  And no len1.  Just a pointer to the string.

It might be interesting to experiment and see how long a string you can support.  Using `mul %%bl`, `add %%ax` and `short result` works for tiny strings like these, but will eventually be insufficient as the strings get longer (requiring `eax` or `rax` etc).  I'll leave that for you too.  Warning: There's a trick when moving 'up' from `mul %%bl` to `mul %%bx`.

One last point about *letting the compiler do as much work as possible tends to produce the most efficient code*: Sometimes people assume that since they are writing assembler, this will result in faster code than if they write it in C.  However, these people fail to take into account the fact that the entire purpose of a C compiler is to turn your C code into assembler.  When you turn on optimization (`-O2`), the compiler is almost certainly going to turn your (well-written) C code into better assembler code than anything you can write by hand.

There are thousands of tweaks and tricks like the ones I've mentioned here.  And the people who write compilers know them all.  While there are a few places where inline asm can make sense, smart programmers leave this work to the lunatics who write compilers whenever possible.  See also [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).

I realize this is just a school project and you are only doing what your teacher requires, but since she has elected to use the most difficult way possible to teach you asm, perhaps she failed to mention that the thing you are doing is something you should (almost) never do in real life.

This post turned out longer than I expected.  Hopefully there is information here that you can use.  And forgive my attempts at Polish labels.  Hopefully I haven't said anything obscene...

Comment: `xor ecx,ecx` is more efficient than `xor rcx,rcx`.  (1 fewer byte, and  Silvermont / KNL only recognize xor-zeroing idioms with 32-bit operand size, not 64).  So `xor %r10d,%r10d` is better on some CPUs than `xor %r10,%r10` even though it's the same size, and equal on other CPUs.)